# Why can't I see my published android app?

Tags: android

I understand it takes some time before it is searchable in the play store, but even if I use the https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=packagename direct link it tells me it can't be found. The developer console says it's published and in production.

Any idea what I may have done wrong?

Comment: What is the packagename?

Comment: How long have you waited?

Comment: The package name is com.colten.dualshok

Comment: I published it under a different package name and waited several hours then To try to fix it I published a new app (same app) with a different package name. It's only been half an hour or so.

Comment: @user2899217 You gotta have patience. I have published a few apps before, one of them only took 2 hours to become available, but another one took almost one whole day.

Answer (score 3):

After clicking publish, you may have to wait up to 24 hours for the app to be available on the market.

This includes the custom URL. Just give it time.

Comment: Oh ok. I saw another stackoverflow answer that said the url was instant. I guess I'll wait it out.